# How to get an IP address in iOS 9 using NSURLSession class

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have multiple hardware devices that contain mini web servers which because they use DHCP can have any IP address on the local domain.

I use NSURLSession to scan through the range of IP Addresses .2 to .253 trying to GET an index.html that these devices host.

This works great as long as I have App Transport Security turned off, of course as soon as I turn it on the calls fail because it doesn't allow IP address connections.

Is there anyway to do this short of leaving ATS off and praying Apple allows me through when I explain the need?

A bit of pseudo code :)

```
App figures out its own IP address say 192.168.0.10
for i in 2..<254 {
    creates a new ip address of 192.168.0.2, .3, .4 etc etc
    NSURLSession to https://above IP address/index.html
    if ( succeeds ) {
         I found a device
    }
}
```

Turn on ATS and this is no longer allowed

Comment: You will need to disable ATS and explain why.  Personally, I think Apple are going to have to be quite lenient when it comes to enforcing the ATS requirement as there are an awful lot of embedded and IoT devices that are never going to support TLS with proper certificates.  You are also going to have deal with the requirement for your app to function correctly on pure IPv6 networks...

Comment: You could always have one server that does the scan for you and maintains a list of valid IP addresses. Then connect to that server via HTTPS and have it return you the IP at which the device was found + the index.html page.

Comment: The server idea is a good one, but this is meant for a small business to use an iPad and possibly multiple pin pads so they're not going to want to have that extra cost/hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You can use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate for the IP address, then provide a means for the user to paste in either allowed keys or allowed custom root certs (your choice), then [override TLS chain validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) in a way that automatically accepts responses that either A. pass the normal cert checks or B. match those specified keys or are signed by those root certs.

I'm not saying that this is trivial, but it can be done.

With that said, you really shouldn't be probing a network like that.  You should use service discovery.  That won't help with the certificate problem, but it will make your app a lot less likely to get rejected for abusing the LAN.  :-)